# Show that the gradient of the curve is positive for all x in the given interval (for a trig function)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I am given the following question:

> The equation of a curve is $\ y = \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$ for $−π<x<π$. Show that
> the gradient of the curve is positive for all $x$ in the given interval.

I've successfully differentiated the curve's equation to get:

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1 + cosx}$

My last issue is mathematically proving that the derivative function stays above 0 for all values of x. I understand that $\ -1 < \cos x < 1 $, so $\ 0 < \cos x + 1 < 2$. However, how do I figure out the max and min values that the derivative function $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1 + cosx}$ can take?

P.S.: I'm still learning formatting equations and such into the correct format, and am using this place as an alternative to no teachers and peers due to the virus situation (have AP-equivalent calc exams soon).

Comment: did you mean $x$ when you wrote $\theta$?

Comment: $$\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that
$$\frac{\sin{x}}{1+\cos{x}}=\frac{2\sin\frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{2}}{1+2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-1}=\frac{2\sin\frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{2}}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}=\tan\frac{x}{2}$$
And we know that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan\frac{x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}$$
As something squared is always positive, then the gradient must **always** be positive as required.
(Note: we have proved a stronger result; namely that the gradient is positive for all $x\in\mathbb R$, not just in the given interval.)

**EDIT:**
In answer to your comment:
We have
$$0<1+\cos{x}<2$$
Assuming you understand why this true, consider
$$\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}$$
If $1+\cos{x}$ is very very very close to $2$, which is possible according to the inequality, then $\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}$ is very very very close to- but **very slightly greater**- than $\frac{1}{2}$. (If you have trouble understanding why, here's another example: $\frac{1}{1.9}>\frac{1}{2}$.) So we have
$$\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}>\frac{1}{2}$$
However, if $1+\cos{x}$ is very close to $0$, then the expression $\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}$ gets extremely big; mathematically we say that as $1+\cos{x}$ approaches $0$, then $\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}$ approaches infinity, or $\infty$ if you prefer.

Obviously, for the values of $1+\cos{x}$ in between $0$ and $2$, the value of $\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}$ will be 'between' $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\infty$.

So, we can write that
$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}<\infty$$
ie $$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}$$ as required. Remember; anything divide by $0$ is infinitely large, **not** $0$ (I believe that's the mistake that the examiners were alluding to). I hope that helps. If not, don't hesitate to ask any further questions.

Good luck in your A Levels, from one A-Level Student to another :)

Comment: got it. In my A Level examiner report, it says 

"Much better were candidates who produced a sketch or stated $\ –1 < cos x < 1$, so $\ 0 < 1 + cos x $ or $\ 0 < 1 + cos x < 2$. Unfortunately then many of these candidates undid all their previously excellent work by making an incorrect statement, such as $\ 0 < 1/(1 + cos x) < ½$, instead of $\  ½ < 1/(1 + cos x)$."




Can you show me how, exactly, to get to $ \ ½ < 1/(1 + cos x) $?

Comment: @Mathematician I have edited my answer in response to your comment, I hope it helps. By the way, it's nice to be speaking to another A-Level student on this site, I have my exams this year too (assuming you're in Year 2 of your courses, which I assume you are as differentiation of trig functions is only in Year 2 Pure). Good luck in your coming exams :)

Comment: I see light now, thank you. Yes! My weakest point is definitely trigonometry. I’m slowly inching my way up there.

Comment: @Mathematician I'm glad to help :) Which Maths A Level course are you taking? Edexcel?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that your function is undefined at $x=-\pi$. So I think the interval should be $-\pi<x<\pi$.

As @lab bhattacharjee mentioned in the comments we have $\cos(2x)=2\cos^{2}(x)-1$ so $$\cos(x)=2\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})-1$$ and $\cos(x)+1=2\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2}).$

Clearly $\cos^{2}(\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos^{2}(\frac{-\pi}{2})=0$, $\cos^2(0)=1$ and it follows that $0<2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})\leq2$ for all $x\in(-\pi,\pi).$

Hence $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{2\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}$$ and from the previous calculations we have $\frac{1}{2\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for $-\pi<x<\pi.$

Answer (score 0):

Expressed  in terms of half angles

$$ y=\dfrac{2sc}{2cc}= \tan \frac x2$$

Its derivative $\dfrac{1}{2\cos^2(x/2)}$ is always $>0$ and increases monotonously between x-limits $\pm \pi. $

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: That is correct. But at the end of interval there is an asymptote slope jump discontinuity $ -\infty \; to +\infty$. so...

Comment: I assume you mean that the value of $y$ jumps from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Yes.as well as the slope,, as well as curvature and so on..